# Override saveCompat for WordPress Media Uploader

Tags: wordpress, backbone.js, overriding, media, uploader

I am new to `Backbone`, so can't understand what I am doing wrong. What I need is to override saveCompat (`media-models.js` `line 310`, `WP 3.9.1`). I am trying to do it same way I have overridden some media views

```
wp.media.model.Attachment = wp.media.model.Attachment.extend({

    saveCompat: function( data, options ) {
        some code here...
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work for me. `Native WordPress saveCompat` is executed. At the same time the very same idea is perfectly working for `wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat` for example

```
wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat = wp.media.view.AttachmentCompat.extend({

    save: function( event ) {
        some code here...
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The correct way to extend it is:

```
_.extend( wp.media.model.Attachment.prototype, {

    saveCompat: function( data, options ) {
        some code here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `_.extend` removes the ability to call the super class implementation of methods. The proper (or at least a working) way to do it is to use Backbone's `extend` method and then overwrite the prototype in `wp.media.model.Attachment` like this:

```
var MediaCreditAttachmentModel = wp.media.model.Attachment.extend( {
        saveCompat: function( data, options ) {
           ...
        }
} );

wp.media.model.Attachment.prototype = MediaCreditAttachmentModel.prototype;
```